# Visual studio: What does the rectangular mark mean

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I use visual studio 2013. What does the following mark mean? How to add/remove it?
[image]

Udpate: on the line 2347

Comment: Is it the line that currently contains the caret? Or is it one of the lines that contains the highlighted reference (in this case, `setSnappables`)?

Comment: @CodyGray the line 2347

Comment: this is the location of cursor I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a find result matching line indicator. It appears when you double-click any line in the **Find Results** window list. You can remove it by clicking **Clear all** in the Find Results window.